# Request queues in I/O scheduling Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was searching for a way to find out the length of a *request_queue* 
(that is defined as a structure in *linux/include/linux/blkdev.h*). 
However I am new to the kernel development and can't figure out where is 
the actual list of requests to be processed by an elevator.
Is there a way to iterate requests in a queue or at least find a number 
of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests of a queue are linked by `struct list_head queue_head`. You can iterating all the request using the linked list functions, you can see some examples here:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/blkdev.h?v=2.4.37#L271